# Hibernate ManyToMany Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, set, spring-data

I have ManyToMany relationships in Hibernate

Project.class

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_projects",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}
)
private Set<User> projectUsers = new HashSet<>();
```

User.class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
            mappedBy="projectUsers",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Project> userProjects = new HashSet<>();
```

And when I get current user thru

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal User user
```

I have Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception when user.getUserProjects();

Answer (score 1):

It's because when using `@ManyToMany`, first all `Project`s of user are fetched, then all `User`s of fetched `Project`s and so on... This cyclic dependency causes the error, because there is eager fetching missing on `Project` side.

The solution would be to use:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_projects",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}
)
private Set<User> projectUsers = new HashSet<>();
```

Although I do not recommend this solution, because of performance issues (and possible side effects). Better solution would be to have an entity for join table.

Comment: Adding @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) doesn't work for me( Can you give an example with entity for join table please

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @Transactional maybe can solved it because
the @Transactional annotation on the getFavorites() method indicates that the session will be closed at the end of this method